# How to store user input prompt in SAS EG?

Tags: sas

I am using SAS EG 7.1, have created few macro prompts in the project. However, I am having some difficulty to store user input of prompt in the project. Any idea on how to do it? Much thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "store ... in the project"?  The SAS code that is run with the values of the prompt could store the value into datasets or outputs it generates.  Or are you asking how to set default values for the prompts?  Or perhaps how to allow users to change the default values for the prompts?

Answer (score 0):

Prompts are global variables in the Sas EG session. Once the user sets them with s value, they will retain their value until modified. you can attach the prompts to things in the process flow in the properties window of that item.